# How to dispose a SQL connection in c# in a best way?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, ado.net

I have disposed of my `SqlConnection` this way:

```
sqlcon.open();
sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlcom.close();
```

but I am not satisfied with this way of disposing it.

Comment: What makes you unsatisfied in the current code?

Answer (score 5):

The `using` will take care of it for you. Under the hood, `SqlConnection.Dispose()` calls the `SqlConnection.Close()` method, and `SqlCommand.Dispose()` calls `SqlCommand.Close()`.

As additional background, a `using statement` is syntactic sugar for a `try ... finally` that disposes the `IDisposable` object in the `finally`.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly makes you feel unsatisified? Everthing in your code is fine, except the fact that you could put it into a using-statement to ensure it gets disposed even on an error - e.g. an exception:

```
using (var sqlconn = new ...)
using (var sqlcom = new ...)
{
    sqlcon.open();
    sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

This way `Dispose` (which automatically calls `Close`)  is called when leaving the `using`, be it in a usual way or by an exception.